# Matplotlib: Probability Mass Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why does the total probability exceed 1?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

figure, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1)
axes.hist(x = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], density = True)
figure.show()
```

[image]

Expected y-values: [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]

Comment: You plot the probability ***density***. Not the mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is my understanding as per the documentation. I don't claim to be an expert in matplotlib nor I am one of the authors. Your question made me think and then I read the documentation and took some logical steps to understand it. So **this is not an expert opinion**.

**===================================================================**

Since you have not passed bins information, matplotlib went ahead and created its own bins. In this case the bins are as below.

```py
bins = [0.1 , 0.13, 0.16, 0.19, 0.22, 0.25, 0.28, 0.31, 0.34, 0.37, 0.4 ]
```

You can see the **bind width is 0.03**.

Now according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

> density : bool, optional 
>   If True, the first element of the return
>   tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density,
>   i.e., the area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1. This
>   is achieved by dividing the count by the number of observations times
>   the bin width and not dividing by the total number of observations.

In order to make the sum to 1, it is normalizing the counts so that when you multiply the **resulting normalized** counts in each bin with bin width the resulting sum of the individual product becomes 1.
Your counts are as below for X = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]

```py
OriginalCounts = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

As you can see if you multiply the OriginalCounts array with the bin width and sum  all of them, it is going to come out to 4*0.03 = 0.12 .. which is less than one.

So according to the documentation we need to divide the OriginalCounts array with a factor .. which is (number of observations * bin width).

In this case the number of observations are 4 and bin width is 0.03. So 4*0.03 is equal to 0.12. Thus you divide each element of OriginalCounts with 0.12 to get a Normalized histogram values array.

That means that the revised counts are as below

```py
NormalizedCounts = [8.33333333, 0. , 0. , 8.33333333, 0. , 0. , 8.33333333, 0. , 0. , 8.33333333]
```

Please note that, now, if you sum the Normalized counts multiplied by bin width, it will be equal to 1. You can quickly check this: **8.333333*4*0.03=0.9999999..** which is very close to 1.

**This normalized counts is finally shown in the graph.** This is the reason why the height of the bars in the histogram is close to 8 for at four positions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh thanks, how would you make the bin width such that each height is 0.25?

Comment: @NoName ..I don't thin it is possible to have four heights of 0.25 for the data you have provided x=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4] . for any bin width ..if density=True. Because 0.25 * 4 * Bin_Width = 1 <-- If you will solve this ..you will get a Bin_Width = 1 .. This is self-contradictory because for a Bin_Width of 1 you can't have four peaks.  You can have a single peak height of 0.25 if your bin width is 4 units wide and covers 0.1 to 0.4 (both inclusive). One of many possible commands that will give such a plot is "plt.figure();plt.hist(x=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4], bins=[0,4], density=True); plt.show();"